# how to separate single pdf into multiple pages using laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on some project. They need split a PDF feature for his webiste.

How do I separate a PDF file into pages pdf. I have tried [www.splitapdf.com](http://www.splitapdf.com) for split my pdf into separate pages but I need an offline solution for my project work into laravel. I am tring some laravel packages but it is not working properly. I want to separate single pdf into multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

I use [tcpdf](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf) for this like:

```
$tcpdf->AddPage();
$tcpdf->setSourceFile('some_pdf_file.pdf');
$tplIdx = $tcpdf->importPage(1); // 1 is first page of pdf
$tcpdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0);
```

Comment: How do you loop through it though and separate each page individually?

Comment: If you know the total number of pages in your pdf you can do it with a for loop and to seperate pages you do the exact same as in my example code and change the page number, for example page 2 will be $tcpdf->importPage(2);